# While importing pywinauto in Tkinter window size changes

Tags: python, tkinter, import, resolution, pywinauto

Here's a snippet of my test code

```
from tkinter import *

master=Tk()
master.geometry('640x340')
Button(master,text='check').pack()

def new():
    print('done')
    from pywinauto import Desktop, Application

master.after(1000,new)
master.mainloop()
```

In exactly one second the tkinter window which is created reduces in size, same thing happens for the button as well. This is just test code which I wrote after tracking down this problem in the application I am trying to build. Could somebody tell me why the window changes in size, and what I can do to prevent this?

I have checked all I could, the official documentation only mentions Tkinter once and that is referring to pywinauto’s backend, and I don't think it is relevant. [Here](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pywinauto/0.6.1/pywinauto.pdf) on page 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs from `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto **win32functions.py** SetProcessDpiAwareness`.

So the method to solve this problem is like this:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(0)
from tkinter import *

master=Tk()
master.geometry('640x340')
Button(master,text='check').pack()

def new():
    print('done')
    from pywinauto import Desktop, Application

master.after(1000,new)
master.mainloop()
```